# Jboss 5.0.1 GA InterceptorRegistry Console WARN messages - How to remove?

Tags: jboss

I see warnings like the following on my JBOSS console. What are they and how do I remove them ? Configuring the CONSOLE logging level to ERROR in server\all\conf\jboss-log4j.xml didn't work either.

```
10:18:50,656 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for public void net.massmatrix.metadb.core.session.beans.PermissionsManagerBean.updatePermissionsAfterReasoning(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
10:18:50,671 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for public net.massmatrix.metadb.core.dataobject.FileInformation net.massmatrix.metadb.core.session.beans.PermissionsManagerBean.getFileInfo(int,int)
10:18:50,687 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for public java.util.ArrayList net.massmatrix.metadb.core.session.beans.PermissionsManagerBean.getObjectsAccessTo(int)
10:18:50,703 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for public java.util.ArrayList net.massmatrix.metadb.core.session.beans.PermissionsManagerBean.getPermissions(int,int)
10:18:50,718 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for public void net.massmatrix.metadb.core.session.beans.PermissionsManagerBean.updatePermissions(int,java.util.Map,boolean)
10:18:50,734 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for public void net.massmatrix.metadb.core.session.beans.PermissionsManagerBean.updatePermissions(int,java.util.Map)
10:18:50,750 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for public void net.massmatrix.metadb.core.session.beans.PermissionsManagerBean.removePermission(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)
10:18:50,765 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for public void net.massmatrix.metadb.core.session.beans.PermissionsManagerBean.changePermission(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,net.massmatrix.metadb.core.entity.common.enums.Permission)
10:18:50,781 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for public void net.massmatrix.metadb.core.session.beans.PermissionsManagerBean.updatePermissionsAfterReasoning(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
10:18:50,781 WARN  [InterceptorRegistry] applicable interceptors is non-existent for public net.massmatrix.metadb.core.dataobject.FileInformation net.massmatrix.metadb.core.session.beans.PermissionsManagerBean.getFileInfo(int,int)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [JBoss issue](http://community.jboss.org/message/344674#344674) that can be ignored.  Are you running the latest available version?

You ought to be able to block this by adding

```
<category name="org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.registry.InterceptorRegistry">
 <priority value="ERROR"></priority>
</category>
```

to jboss-log4j.xml.